# Getting an interactive webpage with curl

Tags: php, apache, curl

General Info:

I am currently working on `domain.com`, which is public. On `m1.domain.com` is a private server that is accessible from `domain.com`.

What I need to do:

I need to get a webpage from `m1.domain.com` and add it to a php webpage in `domain.com`. If `m1` was not private, `iframe` would be perfect, but it is.

What I have done:

So far I have manged to get the page and make it accessible. When I access `domain.com\m1` I am redirected to the login page, but as soon as I enter my credentials and press enter, curl fails to manage the next redirection instead it changes the url in the browser from `domain.com\m1` to `domain.com\session`. It is important to note that when I login from `m1.domain.com`, the next page is `m1.domain.com\session`.

**Questions:**

1) Why is redirection failing even though I have used:

```
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

2) Also if you have any other comments on how to make it work properly, let me know.

Here is the whole code:

```
<?php

    define("COOKIE_FILE", "cookie.txt");

    # Login the user
    $ch = curl_init('');
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE_FILE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "m1.domain.com");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $output;
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```